# CakePHP server configuration - incorrect paths

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, server, document-root

I am just getting started with CakePHP and I'm having some trouble getting the default page to show correctly.

**Current Server Directories**

```
wamp
  www
    FIRSTStudioCake
       bin
       config
       logs
       plugins
       src
       tests
       ...
       webroot
       ...
       .htaccess
       ...
       index.php
       ...
```

Currently, the home page looks like this: 
[image]

Upon further inspection, I found that the paths to the css were incorrect.

`/FIRSTStudioCake/css/bake.css` is produced by CakePHP
`/FIRSTStudioCake/webroot/css/bake/css` is the file it should be referencing.

What am I doing wrong here?

I have a feeling this has to do something with changing DocumentRoot somewhere, but due to my inexperience with server configuration, I'm pretty lost.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

WAMP disables rewrite_module by default, so all I had to do was uncomment `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in the httpd.conf and restart my server.